# Suspicious temp = temp.next

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I was practising some linked list problems in python, and this is my complete code to give the linked list nodes from the user and then print them:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class linkList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

# In this program, first, we get linked list nodes from users 
# and then we will try to print all the nodes


GivenNode = input("please enter the first node")
OurList = linkList()
OurList.head = Node(GivenNode)

# Since now, temp is our node that was doing something on it:
temp = ourList.head

while (1):


    GivenNode = input("Please enter the next node and if that ends, please type end:")

    if(GivenNode == "end"):
        break

    temp.next = Node(GivenNode)
    temp = temp.next

# Now we want to print all nodes 
temp_2 = OurList.head

while( temp_2.next != None ):

    print(temp_2.data)
    temp_2=temp_2.next
```

I cannot understand :

```
temp = temp.next
```

I think that will delete the memory of the temp...
But when I want to print all nodes, they already exist!
How?

Comment: "I think that will delete memory of temp." well, it doesn't. Why do you think that? Python doesn't' give you *any* direct control over memory management. You cannot manually delete on object.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga But when we want to delete a note how we use temp=None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp` is just a reference. When you initialize `OurList` and add a `Node` to its `head`, you have created the instances in memory. `temp` is just a reference to these instances and can be updated anytime.

Let's start with `temp = OurList.head`.

```
GivenNode = 1
OurList = linkList()
OurList.head = Node(GivenNode)  // Node1

temp = OurList.head  // here temp = Node1

GivenNode = 2 
temp.next = Node(GivenNode)  // temp = Node1, temp.next = OurList.head.next = Node2
temp = temp.next  // temp = Node2
```

See?
First, there is a class instance for `Node` initialized. This class has a memory address `Address A` and is stored in the `head` of an `LinkedList` instance.

On each loop, there are two operations being performed.

1. `next` attribute of the `Node` class gets pointed to a new `Node` instance using `temp.next`, stored at `Address B`
2. after this initialization, `temp` is reinitialized to the `Node` instance at `Address B`. So next loop will have `Node` instances at `Address C` and so on.

So, instances are getting pointed to one another, everything is in memory, `temp` just keeps going from one node to another, creating new connections along the way.

Now when you initialize `temp_2 = OurList.head`, `temp_2` is now pointing to an instance on memory address `Address A`, and the loop just goes through all the connections made by `temp` in the previous loop.

In short, `temp` and `temp_2` are just some references pointing to some instance at any given point of time. You are only changing the instance to which these variables point to at any given point of time, the whole data is still intact in memory, and can be referenced by `OurList.head`, `OurList.head.next`, `OurList.head.next.next` and so on.